# One string variable for each tablerow

Tags: javafx, tableview

Is there any way to add an unique string(message) that shows on double click to each table row? I got the code for showing the message using PopUp, but how can I have a unique message(string) for each TableRow?

Right now I have `List<String> rowMessages = new ArrayList();`

and I do

```
 tableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {

        TableRow<ObservableList> row = new TableRow<>();

        row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2 && (!row.isEmpty())) {
            System.out.print(rowMessages.get(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex);
            }
        });

        return row;

    });
```

This of course isn't a good approach - and if the user filter or sort, the indexes aren't correct according to the indexes in the list rowMessages any more.

Using a model isn't an option, as the data is added dynamically from a database the user chose. I also doesn't iterate the rows in the tableview right now.

Comment: Why not just use `row.getItem()`?

Comment: The message isn't in the tableview, it should just be shown when the user double clicks a row. Doesn't get item get the data in the row? How would you set the message then? I don't loop through the rows now, so perhaps I need an extra loop for setting?

Comment: @James_D By the way, I store data in fields and columns, and for that reason I never actually iterate the rows. Instead, to visualise my columns and fields in a tableview I transpose the data.